# Run WCF service with many connections

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to tun `WCF` service that could support several client types for example `soap 1.1` and `soap 1.2`? Currently I have service with configuration below. I'm write that to support several connections I need to edit configuration file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what you're looking for is multiple endpoints.  One contract, 2 or more endpoints.  You could have one endpoint for SOAP 1.1 and another for SOAP 1.2.  Use `basicHttpBinding` for 1.1, `wsHttpBinding` for 1.2.   They'll need different relative addresses.   Also note that you appear to have posted the client ocnfiguration - these changes need to be made on the server's config.

Comment: See [Multiple Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN for a starting point.